# Cant read web2py uploaded .txt from the shell

Tags: file-upload, web2py

I have a simple table:

```
db.define_table('myfiles',
    Field('title','string'),
    Field('myfile','upload))
```

Then i run my app from shell:

```
python web2py.py -S myapp -M
```

Choose my file_path:

```
file_path = os.path.join(request.folder,'upload',db.myfiles[1].myfile)
```

but then i try to read my uploaded file, i get "File not open for reading"

```
with open(file_path, 'wb') as f: data = f.readlines()
```

I even tried the same process with copy-paste my file to private folder but still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

First, the default folder for uploaded files is "uploads", not "upload":

```
file_path = os.path.join(request.folder, 'uploads', db.myfiles[1].myfile)
```

Second, you should open the file for reading rather than writing:

```
with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
    data = f.readlines()
```